# Android Navigation Drawer remove Actionbar

Tags: android

So I chose to use the Navigation Drawer from Android and want to know if it's possible to remove the actionbar?

I tried to choose the noactionbar option as theme, but the app crashed:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Is there any way to remove the actionbar?

edit:

```
02-25 14:24:55.696    1894-1900/? E/MP-Decision﹕ DOWN cpu:2 core_idx:2 Ns:2.100000 

Ts:240 total_time_down:242.000000
02-25 14:24:55.857     693-1263/? E/EnterpriseContainerManager﹕ ContainerPolicy Service is not yet ready!!!
02-25 14:24:55.857  31099-31099/at.x.music93 E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-25 14:24:55.947  31099-31099/at.x.music93 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.x.music93/at.x.music93.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
            at at.x.music93.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at at.x.music93.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreateView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:97)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:879)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1155)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4966)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
            at at.x.music93.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 14:24:56.277    693-31450/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
02-25 14:24:56.547  31457-31457/? E/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file
02-25 14:24:56.547  31457-31457/? E/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9505_4.3_0018
```

Comment: edited it with the crash log.

Comment: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class fragment there seems to be error in your xml file

Comment: I can't find the error in the XML File, may it be that i have to remove all click listeners that listen for a click in the action bar?

Comment: check your crash log its saying like that.

Comment: Your crash points to a NullPointerException in line 97 of `at.x.music93.NavigationDrawerFragment`. What could be null here? My guess is a call to `getActionBar()` or similar.